# How to display only a certain number of pages when viewed in mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass, pagination

I have this pagination that display 8 pages at a time on the desktop. However, on the mobile I would like to display only 4 pages. Is there a way to achieve this through css?

```css
.paginationExample {
  padding: 0 9px;
  margin: 12px 0 0 10px;
  float: left;
  width: 92%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  }
  
  a {
    display: inline-table;
    padding: 1px 2px;
    margin: 0 1px;
    color: #000;
  }
```

```html
<div class="paginationExample">
  <span class="disabledPrevBttn"></span>
  <span class="pageCurrent">1</span>

  <a href="#/2">2</a>
  <a href="#/3">3</a>
  <a href="#/4">4</a>
  <a href="#/5">5</a>
  <a href="#/6">6</a>
  <a href="#/7">7</a>
  <a href="#/8">8</a>
  <a href="#/9">9</a>
  <a href="#/10">10</a>
  <a href="#/11">11</a>
  <a href="#/12">12</a>
  <a href="#/13">13</a>
  <a href="#/14">14</a>
  <a href="#/15">15</a>
</div>

Additional HTML:

<router-link v-if="myprevLink" :to="'/' + myprevLink">
      <i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i><span class = "activePrevBttn"> Previous</span>
</router-link>
    <span class="disabled" v-else
      ><i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i><span class = "disabledPrevBttn"> Previous</span>
    </span>

<router-link v-if="mynextLink" :to="'/' + mynextLink">
      <span class = "activeNextLink">Next</span><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i>
</router-link>
    <span class="disabled" v-else>
      <span class = "disabledNextLink">Previous</span><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i>
    </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than making it mobile phone vs desktop, you should be use the width of the screen to decide how many pages option you want to include in pagination.

```
 if(window.innerWidth < 650) {
    //  set the pageCount = 8    
    }
```

Comment: can you expand on this? How would I show only 8 page? I have set the pageCount  = 8

Comment: I meant that only, i just want to say its more about the browser screen size rather than mobile vs destop view.